# Using the function SPLIT_PART twice in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `TEXT` column where each text is formatted as such:

`/customers/{customer_id}/views/{id1}~{id2}/`

I am trying to fetch the `id2` only.

My idea is how to split the string by the `/` character first, where I will have:

`customers`, `{customer_id}`, `views`, `{id1}~{id2}`.

And then, get the last position:

`{id1}~{id2}`. And then split it again by the `~` character, and finally get the last position.

The issue is that I am new to SQL and I have no idea if this is even possible. How can I do that and end up with only one column?

```sql
SELECT 
  split_part(thetext, '/', 4) as temp
  // how do I proceed from here?
FROM mytable
```

EDIT:
Some examples:

`/customers/1231341/views/1312391293~3432491/`
`/customers/2213441/views/424131~231321341/`

The IDs are of different lengths as well.

Comment: Or you could do: `select split_part(rtrim('/customers/{customer_id}/views/{id1}~{id2}/', '/'), '~', 2); {id2}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html) to capture the part you want while matching the whole input, and replacing (the whole input) with the capture:

```
select regexp_replace(thetext, '.*~(.*)/', '\1') as temp
from mytable
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/44f69/2).